# Angular <textarea> FormControl & HTML entities

Tags: php, angular, html-entities

I am likely missing something painfully obvious, so grab your popcorn and get ready for a laugh.

I am currently struggling with handling HTML entities, specifically, getting Angular to render them correctly. I am aware of the existence of the DOMSanitizer and how to use it, but I don't think it's the correct solution for my situation.

Users are able to submit forms that contain `<textarea>` inputs. Users should be able to submit text that contains HTML entities.
After submitting, our PHP server encodes this text using `htmlspecialchars` and stores the result in our DB.
If a user wants to write `\<script type="javascript">alert('hello');\</script>`, then there must be a way for that to be rendered. Also, as far as I can tell, this code snippet is also exactly why I can use the `DOMSanitizer`'s `byPassSecurity` functions...right?

**The Problem**
The user now goes back to the previous form to edit their text. Currently my Angular app displays the *encoded* HTML entities (e.g. "&lt;" instead of "<"). I am using ReactiveForms.

**The Question**
What is the best practice for rendering the symbol for an HTML entity within a `FormControl`?
I have found plenty of solutions that implement custom pipes which make use of RegExp replacements and the sort, but surely there is a mechanism baked into either the browser or Angular?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: _"our PHP server encodes this text using htmlspecialchars and stores the result in our DB"_ - and there's your mistake. You should insert the _raw_ data into your database. Applying `htmlspecialchars` is appropriate whenever you bring that data into the context "HTML". The database is a completely separate context.

Comment: whether I encode the text before it's stored in the DB or when it's retrieved from the DB has the same effect; the client gets encoded text.
could you provide more details around how to correctly render the HTML entity within the HTML context, when Angular is at work?